# What's the difference between indexed and non-indexed field in Views and Search API?

Tags: views, entities, search

I'm using Search API with a database backend and Views to build the search results page. More specifically, I'm using fields in Views. When selecting fields, I see two options for example:

- Title
- Title (indexed field)

When using this field, I get the same result. So I'm wondering why might I use the indexed version over the regular?

[image]

Comment: Simple:
`Title` provided for Views from Entity.
`Title (indexed field)` provided for Views from SOLR.

For example: 
If you use `Title` as filter - Drupal will use it by own filter handlers. So first, it will request data from SOLR (for example 100 found rows), then Views make filter on found rows, reducing it to 10 found rows - as you see - it's not good for performance.
Better is using `Title (indexed field)`, that will request only 10 records from SOLR server.

Against, `title` will more preferred for outputs, than indexed fields (for some cases).

Comment: TLDR: `Indexed field` grabs the field from the search API index, rather than the Drupal database. So `Indexed field` probably the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Nikit That seems an answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ok, I have copy to answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

- **Title** provided for Views from Content entity.
- **Title (indexed field)** provided for Views from SOLR.

For example: You have 1000 contents, and you want to show 10 of these, titles of that starts "Z" letter.

If you use `Title` as filter - Drupal will use it by Views handlers, so:

1. It will request data from SOLR server, in our case - all 1000 items.
2. The Views filter on found items, reducing it to the required 10 "Z" contents.

As you see - *it's not good for performance*. Better is using `Title (indexed field)`as Views filter, that will request only required **10 records** from SOLR server.

p.s. Against it, `title` will prefer for Views output than indexed field (*for some cases*).